Disable certain tests from dbt a package
I am using a package inside my dbt project that has several sources defined. Only some of the sources are relevant so that I disabled all the other sources in the dbt_project.yml. Some of the disabled sources have tests defined that throw warnings on the console when I run my dbt models.
...
[WARNING]: Test 'test.my_package.source_not_null_some_disable_source' (models/sources_source_name.yml) depends on a source named 'source_name.table_name' which is disabled
...

I can get rid of the warnings if I disable all tests of the package in the dbt_project.yml
tests:
  my_package:
    +enabled: false

But I would prefer to disable only the tests from the disabled sources.
Is it possible to make the selection more fine grained to disable only tests for specific sources from my_package?

If there is no too much of tests you can disable them individually:
tests:
  my_package:
    source_not_null_some_disable_source:
        +enabled: false


Hi, thanks for your answer. It does work but I was hoping for a solution to disable all tests coming from a source or the file were some sources are defined.

Yes, surprisingly, I wasn't able to find such a solution either.
